# Storing of passwords

Tags: 2010, 2013, password

I’m looking at a way to store client passwords etc on a sharepoint site.

Does anybody know how I would go about having the passwords stored in the DB with MD5, but unencrypted to the users viewing the site?

Comment: MD5 is a one way HASHing function - you can turn text > MD5  but not the other way around. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secure Store Service.

http://trentacular.com/2010/11/sharepoint-2010-programatically-retrieve-credentials-from-the-secure-store-service/